# Next.js router.push() doesn't work if I use routeChangeStart/routeChangeComplete

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this code that just changes the loading status if url changes.

_app.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteStart = (url, { shallow }) => {
      console.log(url);
      setLoading((p) => !p);
    };

    const handleRouteComplete = (url, { shallow }) => {
      setLoading(false);
    };

    const handleRouteError = (url, { shallow }) => {
      setLoading(false);
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteStart);
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteComplete);
    router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleRouteError);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteStart);
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteComplete);
      router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleRouteError);
    };
  }, []);
```

pages/index.tsx

I use this

router.push("/map"); and it doesn't work...I checked and found out that it is because of routeChangeStart, etc these events

How can I solve this?

index.tsx

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Home(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (cookies(props).firstLaunch === "false") {
    router.push("/map"); <=== doesn't run
    return <LoadingPage title={"title"} />; <=== it executes correctly
  }
  return (
...
  );
}
```

Comment: This might help https://github.com/harm-meijer/nextjs-example/blob/067daa8edaa4998c2a53879cd1f6da41660670f6/pages/_app.js

Comment: @AsitPrakash I don't have a problem with loading state, router.push('/path') doesn't work in index.tsx but in other pages it works fine

Comment: Can you share the part of your code where you are executing router.push('/map') ?

Comment: @AsitPrakash did it

Comment: It's probably not being called to begin with, as you'd get an error when `router.push` gets called during server-side rendering. You should move that logic to the client-side, inside a `useEffect`.